# Ruby RoR split a hash

Tags: ruby, string, split, ruby-hash

I have a hash like this :

```
hash = {"user:**xy@xy.com** password:**azerty**"=>1,
        "user:**yy@yy.com** password:**qwerty**"=>1}
```

How can I extract only the username (email) and the password of each element to use it separately.

With split method eventually. How to split a string from the second `:` for example?

I want to have something like this

```
Username  Password
xy@xy.com azerty
yy@yy.com qwerty
```

Comment: @EricDuminil no, the ** are just used here to bold the **word**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just one more way to handle the situation:

```
hash.keys.to_s.scan(/user:(\w+@\w+.\w+)\spassword:(\w+)/)
#=> [["xy@xy.com", "azerty"], ["yy@yy.com", "qwerty"]]
```

Breakdown:

- `hash.keys.to_s` - an Array of the keys in the Hash (since we don't care about values) converted to a string `"[\"user:xy@xy.com password:azerty\", \"user:yy@yy.com password:qwerty\"]"`
- `scan(/user:(\w+@\w+.\w+)\spassword:(\w+)/)` - an Array of the matching capture groups

[Example](http://rubular.com/r/4L6Tua0zPc)

Comment: Thanks! Simple and efficient. Thanks also for the rubular example

Answer (score 0):

consider below snippet. it will give you a view, that you'll know, where you should start.

```
h.keys().map {|x| x.split(" ")}.each do |e|
  puts "#{e.first.split(":").last}   #{e.last.split(":").last}"
end

# xy@xy.com   azerty
# yy@yy.com   qwerty
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hash.each { |x,y| puts x.split(" ").to_s.gsub("user:", "").to_s.gsub("password:", "") }
# ["xy@xy.com", "azerty"]
# ["yy@yy.com", "qwerty"]
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of Split

```
hash.each do |key, _val|
  puts key.split.map { |s| s.split(':').last }.join(' ')
end
```